# Equivalent of the "Unique" row in Describe() for int/float variables?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I have a dataframe with **strings** and do a `describe()`, I get a very nice dataframe that looks like the below, whereupon you can see the number of unique values in each column and sort upon it:

[image]

However, when I have a dataframe with **integers or floats**, and do a `describe()`, I get a dataframe with the traditional statistics like the one below. There is no `unique` column. Is there a way to retrieve the unique column?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numbers_df.nunique()` as  previously suggested. This will give you a Series with the number of unique values for each column.

If you still want to use the `describe()` function, you could convert your DataFrame to `object`, which will be treated differently than a numbers only DataFrame:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10), 'b': [2]*10, 'c': np.random.randint(10)})
df.astype('object').describe()
```

which will give you:

```
         a   b   c
count   10  10  10
unique  10   1   7
top      0   2   3
freq     1  10   2
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to retrieve the unique column?

Yes.

Use [nunique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html).

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [5, 6, 6, 7]})
>>> df.x.nunique()
3
```